# any plugin in Flutter / Dart same as Java Collator?

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart, locale

Is there any function or plugin in Dart or Flutter same as Java Collator? I want to sort a list of strings according to locale order, instead of simple string sorting by unicode.

Answer (score 0):

See if [sorted](https://pub.dev/packages/sorted) or [sorted_list](https://pub.dev/packages/sorted_list) solves your problem.

Comment: These two provides sorting function, but do not have built-in locale sorting rules, unfortunately.